# Why does this D3 code add the <p> element outside the body, instead of inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm learning D3 and have come across an issue using the select operator.

Specifically, why does the following code add the `<p>` element outside the body, instead of inside it?

`var pData1 = d3.select("body").select("p").data([1]).enter().append("p");`

I am using a totally blank HTML file with just `<head>` and `<body>` tags to test.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you use `selectAll('p')` instead?

Comment: Their is no <p> element in the <body> tag, so you cannot select it. if you want to add a <p> tag, You can append it directly to the body tag.
`d3.select("body").append("p");`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(This repeats the content from Lars Kotthoff's answer, but I'd spent time creating the demo so I thought I'd still post.)

The problem is that `select`, unlike `selectAll`, does not re-define the parent element for elements added in the `enter()` selection.

```
d3.select("body").select("p#a")
    .data([1])
    .enter().append("p").attr("id", "a")
    .text("This paragraph is appended to <html> (the document root) 
          because no selectAll statement reset the parent element.");

d3.selectAll("p#b")
    .data([1])
    .enter().append("p").attr("id", "b")
    .text("This paragraph is appended to <html> 
          because the selectAll statement is called directly on the root.");

d3.selectAll("body").select("p#c")
    .data([1])
    .enter().append("p").attr("id", "c")
    .text("This paragraph is also appended to <html> 
          because the last selectAll statement was called directly from the root.");

d3.select("body").selectAll("p#d")
    .data([1])
    .enter().append("p").attr("id", "d")
    .text("This paragraph is appended to <body> 
          because the selectAll statement is a sub-selection of the body selection.");

d3.selectAll("body").selectAll("p#e")
    .data([1])
    .enter().append("p").attr("id", "e")
    .text("This paragraph is also appended to <body> 
          because the final selectAll statement is a sub-selection of the body.");
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/eLF4H/

It is unusual to use an enter chain after a `select` statement (versus selectAll), because usually you are selecting multiple elements if you are going to do a data join.  However, **if you want to create the element if it doesn't exist or update it if it does**, you have two options:

- use a selectAll statement followed by the data join

  ```
  var pdata1 = d3.select("body").selectAll("p#data") 
                      //select element if it exists
                 .data([dataObject]);  
                      //join to the current data

  pdata1.enter().append("p").attr("id", "data"); 
                      //create element if required

  pdata1.text(function(d){return d.textValue;}); 
                      //set or update the element based on the data
  ```
- use an if statement to create the element if necessary and use [`.datum()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum) to bind the data

  ```
  var pdata1 = d3.select("p#data") 
                      //select element if it exists

  if ( pdata1.empty() ) {
     pdata1 = d3.select("body").append("p").attr("id", "data"); 
                      //create element if required
  }

  pdata1.datum(dataObject)
                      //note that you don't need to put the data into an array
        .text(function(d){return d.textValue;}); 
                      //set or update the element based on the data
  ```

Comment: As usual, you show that you're much better at explaining these things than I am :)

Comment: But you're much better at making sure that *everyone* who posts a d3 question gets some kind of follow up...

Comment: Who knows how long I would have puzzled over this problem if I hadn't found your answer.

Comment: We need more spirit like this on SO ! Both great answers, thanks

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, the way to do what you're trying to do is to use `.selectAll()`. The difference between `.select()` and `.selectAll()` is that `.select()` returns elements while `.selectAll()` returns *elements grouped by ancestor*. This then affects any subsequent `.data()` operations in terms of what the elements are appended to. From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#selectAll):

> Grouping by selectAll also affects subsequent entering placeholder nodes. Thus, to specify the parent node when appending entering nodes, use select followed by selectAll:
>
> d3.select("body").selectAll("div")

Answer (score 2):

there is no p element to select, so I would suggest appending the p element before entering your data:

```
var pData1 = d3.select("body").append("p")

pData1.data([1])...
```

do whatever else you need to do after .data, although there is no need to append another p