# Append element on d3 dragstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3 to make a circle that is draggable, but leaves a copy of the original in place. Here is the circle:

```
g.selectAll('circle')
    .data([{
    cx: 90,
    cy: 80,
    r: 30 }])
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function (d) {return d.cx})
    .attr('cy', function (d) {return d.cy})
    .attr('r', function(d) {return d.r})
    .attr('class','original')
    .call(dragOriginal);
```

Here is the drag behavior:

```
var dragOriginal = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', cloneSpeciesMaker)
    .on('drag', function (d, i) {
    d.cx += d3.event.dx;
    d.cy += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.cx).attr('cy', d.cy)
});
```

And here is the dragstart function:

```
function cloneSpeciesMaker(d) {
    var svg = d3.select('svg');
    //original becomes copy
    d3.select(this)
        .classed('original',false)
        .attr('class','copy');
    // creates new 'original' in place
    var data = [{cx:d.cx,cy:d.cy,r:d.r}];
    svg.append('circle')
        .data(data)
        .attr('class','original')
        .attr("cx",function(d) {return d.x})
        .attr("cy",function(d) {return d.y})
        .attr("r",function(d) {return d.r})
        .style("fill","purple")
        .attr("class","original")
        .call(dragOriginal);
}
```

Right now, I'm succeeding in making the original circle become a 'copy' and dragging it around, but it the part where I append a new circle in its old place isn't working, can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see from the code is in this section:

```
function cloneSpeciesMaker(d) {
    var svg = d3.select('svg');
    //original becomes copy
    d3.select(this)
        .classed('original',false)
        .attr('class','copy');
    // creates new 'original' in place
    var data = [{cx:d.cx,cy:d.cy,r:d.r}]; 
    svg.append('circle')
        .data(data)
        .attr('class','original')
        .attr("cx",function(d) {return d.x})
        .attr("cy",function(d) {return d.y})
        .attr("r",function(d) {return d.r})
        .style("fill","purple")
        .attr("class","original")
        .call(dragOriginal);
}
```

You are setting the data like this

```
var data = [{cx:d.cx,cy:d.cy,r:d.r}];
```

But you are doing which is incorrect d.x and d.y is not defined by you in data.

```
.attr("cx",function(d) {return d.x})
.attr("cy",function(d) {return d.y})
```

This should have been:

```
.attr("cx",function(d) {return d.cx})
.attr("cy",function(d) {return d.cy})
```

Comment: That was probably important but it didn't fix it, the actual issue was using `select` instead of `selectAll`; the circle got appended outside the body of the html, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459834/why-does-this-d3-code-add-the-p-element-outside-the-body-instead-of-inside-it)

Comment: But I do appreciate you catching that mistake so I'll give an upvote anyways!